# Passing derived class as argument to a method meant for a base class parameter - getting an error

Tags: c#, inheritance

Before anyone points out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595059/passing-derived-class-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-when-the-parameter-type-is-base), I have already read it over with no luck.

I have a LatLon class which extends Bing.Maps's Location class ([documentation HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846500.aspx)), mostly to override the GetHashCode and Equals method to perform value equality as opposed to the built-in reference equality, as so:

```
class LatLon : Location
    {
        public readonly double Latitude;
        public readonly double Longitude;

        public LatLon(double Latitude, double Longitude)
        {
            this.Latitude = Latitude;
            this.Longitude = Longitude;
        }

        public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
        {
            // If parameter is null return false.
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
            LatLon p = obj as LatLon;
            if ((System.Object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match:
            return (Latitude == p.Latitude) && (Longitude == p.Longitude);
        }

        public bool Equals(LatLon p)
        {
            // If parameter is null return false:
            if ((object)p == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match:
            return (Latitude == p.Latitude) && (Longitude == p.Longitude);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 13;
            hash = (hash * 92821) + Latitude.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 92821) + Longitude.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

In another class, I'm trying to do the following:

```
LatLon l1 = (LatLon) getBinnedLocation(new LatLon(41, -51.000001));

...

private Location getBinnedLocation(Location loc)
{
    return new Location(
        getBinnedCoord(loc.Latitude, true),
        getBinnedCoord(loc.Longitude, false));
}
```

I'm new to C# coming from Java, but my understanding is that the principles of inheritance and such remain essentially the same. So why is it that the line `LatLon l1 = (LatLon) getBinnedLocation(new LatLon(41, -51.000001));` results in the error: `The best overloaded method match for 'SomeClass.getBinnedLocation(Bing.Maps.Location)' has some invalid arguments`.

It seems like a very simple problem with a very simple solution but I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong.

EDIT:

Proof that my Location is referring to Bing.Maps's Location and not another Location class in my namespace: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxd6z.png.

Picture of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/El1C1.png.

```
Error   3   'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments  C:\...\LatLon.cs    16  15  MapTest
Error   4   The name 'Latitude' does not exist in the current context   C:\...\LatLon.cs    36  21  MapTest
Error   5   'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Latitude' and no extension method 'Latitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\...\LatLon.cs    36  35  MapTest
Error   6   The name 'Longitude' does not exist in the current context  C:\...\LatLon.cs    36  49  MapTest
Error   7   'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\...\LatLon.cs    36  64  MapTest
Error   8   The name 'Latitude' does not exist in the current context   C:\...\LatLon.cs    48  21  MapTest
Error   9   'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Latitude' and no extension method 'Latitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\...\LatLon.cs    48  35  MapTest
Error   10  The name 'Longitude' does not exist in the current context  C:\...\LatLon.cs    48  49  MapTest
Error   11  'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\...\LatLon.cs    48  64  MapTest
Error   12  The name 'Latitude' does not exist in the current context   C:\...\LatLon.cs    54  37  MapTest
Error   13  The name 'Longitude' does not exist in the current context  C:\...\LatLon.cs    55  37  MapTest
Error   14  The best overloaded method match for 'MapTest.MainPage.getBinnedLocation(Bing.Maps.Location)' has some invalid arguments    C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 75  25  MapTest
Error   15  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MapTest.LatLon' to 'Bing.Maps.Location'    C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 75  43  MapTest
Error   16  The best overloaded method match for 'MapTest.MainPage.getBinnedLocation(Bing.Maps.Location)' has some invalid arguments    C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 76  25  MapTest
Error   17  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MapTest.LatLon' to 'Bing.Maps.Location'    C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 76  43  MapTest
Error   18  'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Latitude' and no extension method 'Latitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 79  40  MapTest
Error   19  'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 79  61  MapTest
Error   20  'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Latitude' and no extension method 'Latitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 80  40  MapTest
Error   21  'MapTest.LatLon' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'MapTest.LatLon' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\...\MainPage.xaml.cs 80  61  MapTest
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Location` in `class LatLon : Location` is `Bing.Maps.Location` and not a Location class from some other namespace?

Comment: again with the downvotes?

Comment: Also, not the problem you are asking about but ` (LatLon) getBinnedLocation` will throw a `InvalidCastException` because you are returning a `Location` not a `LatLon` from your function. You can't cast to a more derived type when you create only the base type. You would need to call `new LatLon` instead.

Comment: yes I'm positive, there are no other references to Location in my namespace. When I hover over 'Location' I also see the following: http://i.imgur.com/YHBVllT.png

Comment: It is clear that `getBinnedLocation` doesn't accept an argument of type `LatLon` .  Why don't you try to read about *inheritance* in c#.

Comment: I guess the most realistic solution to my error would just be to change the input and return type to LatLon, but I'd still like to know why I'm getting this error

Comment: @EZI, did you even read my post? LatLon is a derived class of Location

Comment: @youngrrrr *Did you even read* how it works in c#?

Comment: Please post the full text of the error, there should be some more information associated with the error text saying what the invalid arguments are.

Comment: LatLon contains more properties than Location so Laton takes up more memory than Location.  You are tying to cast Location to Laton which is causing an error.  You can't stuff a larger wooden box into a smaller wooden box.  It just doesn't work.

Comment: @jdweng While that is a error with his code that problem would not cause the error the OP is getting.

Comment: I prefaced my post with the fact that I'm new to C#. I'd appreciate helpful replies as opposed to derogatory comments. @EZI

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I did post the full text of the error, word for word. EDIT: that was the wrong pic. Here's one of the error: http://i.imgur.com/tM2bf53.png. My mistake

Comment: @youngrrrr Which image, the only one I see posted by you is http://i.imgur.com/YHBVllT.png which does not have the error in it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - sorry, I realized my mistake and edited my comment. Here it is again anyways for convenience: http://i.imgur.com/tM2bf53.png

Comment: In the meanwhile, does anyone want to explain why this post deserves downvotes or does everyone on SO really have some form of a superiority complex? All these downvotes and still no answers...

Comment: @youngrrrr There are some other major problems with your code that I think if those got fixed it would also fix this problem, can you link to the documetnation of the Bing.Maps.Location class so I can refrence some things and I can post a answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846500.aspx. Thank you for trying to help Scott

Comment: @youngrrrr You're not being downvoted because everyone has a superiority complex. You're being downvoted because the code and corresponding error don't make sense. There has to be another reason for the error than what you've posted.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite I realize it doesn't make sense! That's why I'm posting my question here. I provided as much information as I could relating to the matter. "I don't understand this so let me just downvote it." What? Tell me what I'm doing wrong instead so I can learn and fix my mistakes. Downvotes without explanation doesn't do anything than discourage and piss someone off.

Comment: @youngrrrr The error you give shouldn't happen with the code you provided. There has to be something else that you didn't include. That's why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: Please open up the "Errors" list by going to `View -> Errors List` and post all errors and warnings in to the question in a `<pre> </pre>` block. I think you have more than one error and that is causing the problem.

Comment: @youngrrrr Are `LatLon` and `MapTest.MainPage` in the same assembly? if they are not is it possible that you have multiple `Bing.Maps.Location` classes defined, one in each assembly?

Comment: Scott : At the time I posted my response the only info I had was the following : The best overloaded method match for 'SomeClass.getBinnedLocation(Bing.Maps.Location)' has some invalid arguments.  My response explains this error.  I can't be blamed if additional wrong info was posted after my response.  I still think my response is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your LatLon class that may be causing your issue. See if fixing these problems fix your code.

1. You create your own Latitude and Logitude members. You should not be creating your own, you should be using the underlying class'es members, you can call the underlying class'es  consturctor via `base(`.
2. `getBinnedLocation` returns a `new Location` but you cast it to a `LatLon`, this is going to fail at runtime. Just call `new LatLon` and have it return a `LatLon` instead of a `Location`.
3. Your function uses java's naming style, C# has [its own style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) (Not a error but you should follow conventions of the language you are writing in). Functions should be `PascalCased` not `camelCased`

.

```
class LatLon : Location
{
    //Get rid of these
    //public readonly double Latitude;
    //public readonly double Longitude;

    public LatLon(double latitude, double longitude)
          : base(latitude, longitude) //This calls the base's (double, double) constuctor.
    {
    }

    //... Everything else can stay the same
}



LatLon l1 = GetBinnedLocation(new LatLon(41, -51.000001));

...

private LatLon GetBinnedLocation(Location loc)
{
    return new LatLon(
        getBinnedCoord(loc.Latitude, true),
        getBinnedCoord(loc.Longitude, false));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to your updated question, indeed the reason you are getting your problem (error 15) is errors 1-14 preventing your class from compiling. Fixing 1-14 will fix your error.

From your description it sounds like VS is getting confused about the type. Its acting as if Location is not a defined type. Try to remove the dll refrence the type is defined in and re-add it.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Now when I made modifications to my LatLon class as you described, I got this error: http://imgur.com/BWvyjIR. I actually tried doing what you suggested above before, but for some reason every time I'd refer to base in that manner, VS keeps thinking I'm talking about System.Object and not Bing.Maps's Location. Not sure what to make of this but it could explain why my LatLon type isn't being recognized as a Location...

Comment: @youngrrrr is `Location` defined in your code (for example auto-generated from a web reference) or is it from a dll you are referencing in your project? A easy way to tell is if you right click on `Location` and click `Go to Defination` does it take you to a "Metadata" page or actual code you can edit?

Comment: I am sure that `Location` does not exist in my main space (I have verified this with a search of my entire .sln/project directory), so I'm guessing that has to mean it's an external assembly. EDIT: as per your advice, it takes me to a "Metadata" page

Comment: I get the Metadata page

Comment: I would remove the dll refrence and re-add it. It sounds like VS is getting confused about the type. Its acting as if `Location` is not a defined type.

Comment: That makes sense. This problem doesn't seem to be based on any code-specific errors. I will let you know what the result is and would happily accept your answer if you update it with this fix you suggested instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have a like that looks like `using Location = SomeNameSpace.SomeClass;` at the top of the `LatLon` file? A incorrectly created alias would also cause this behavior.

Comment: I do not. Anyways, it seems like the library I'm working at is closing for the day so I'll try to give you an update once I get back home. Thanks for all your help Scott.

Answer (score -2):

Cast your LatLon instance to a Location when you send it in to the function that takes a location.

Comment: The OP shouldn't have to do this if the class inherits `Location`.