# How to pass derived class as a parameter to a method that asks for a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Note I am a beginner.

I read through this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595059/passing-derived-class-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-when-the-parameter-type-is-base) and I understood that passing a derived class to a method that asks for a base class is totally ok and should work.

Well, I have a class "Enemy" that inherits "PhysicsObject".
However when I wrote the following collision handler and call it with a PhysicsObject and an Enemy:

```
void ProjectileHit(PhysicsObject p, PhysicsObject hit)
{
    hit.TakeDamage(CurrentPlayer.EquippedTool.Damage);
}
```

I get a red line in visual studio saying 
*PhysicsObject does not contain a definition for "TakeDamage".*
The collision handler is part of the framework I use and only accepts an instance of the base class it seems. Is there any way to pass an instance to "Enemy" to that handler and call "TakeDamage" inside of it?

EDIT:
Would this work?

```
void ProjectileHit(PhysicsObject p, PhysicsObject hit)
{
    Enemy e = hit as Enemy;
    e.TakeDamage(CurrentPlayer.EquippedTool.Damage);
}
```

Comment: Either make `TakeDamage` a virtual method of `PhysicsObject` or change the method to take some type that _does_ have that method.

Comment: Well the error is clear, if `PhysicsObject ` does not have an implementation then it won't work. Can you re-work `TakeDamage` ?

Comment: I cannot change the way the collision handler works or the code for PhysicsObject but I can change Enemy and TakeDamage, yes.

Comment: You want to check e for null, since the as-Keyword casts or returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your PhysicsObject does not implement the method TakeDamage (and reading your class names it never should) you can do the following:

```
void ProjectileHit(PhysicsObject p, PhysicsObject hit)
{
    (hit as Enemy)?.TakeDamage(CurrentPlayer.EquippedTool.Damage);
}
```

'as' tries to cast hit to Enemy and returns null if hit is null or the cast fails.

'?' executes the code on its right only if the left side is not null.

Comment: Yeah I just found out about "as" myself and edited it in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Should I remove my question or is it worth saving?