# C# base class/Interface with a generic method that accepts the derived class as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, derived-class

I would like to have a method defined on the base class (and in an interface) that accepts a derived class as its parameter.

i.e.

```
abstract class Base : IBase
{
    public void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(??? destination) {};
}

public class Derived : Base
{
     public override void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(Derived destination)
     {
         blah blah ....
     }
}
```

I would be eternally grateful if someone can tell me what the Interface would look like and how to do this... or if possible

With Anticipation

Lance

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595059/passing-derived-class-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-when-the-parameter-type-is-base

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for:

```
interface IBase<T>
{
    void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(T destination);
}

public abstract class Base<T> : IBase<T>
{
    public virtual void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(T destination) { }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    public override void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(Derived destination)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks @Phil

Comment: The OP says 'and in an interface' so you probably want interface IBase<T> {void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(T destination);}

Comment: Unfortunately for me It looks like I will have to go through my whole project and update every single derived class and add <Derived> to all of my entity classes and derived interfaces which is way to much work at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic class where the generic type have to be of type `IBase` :

```
public abstract class Base<T> : IBase where T : IBase
{
    public virtual void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(T destination) { }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    public override void CloneMeToProvidedEntity(Derived destination)
    {
        // blah blah ....
    }
}
```