# Cannot convert from 'method group' to Action

Tags: c#, subtype

Will be more easy to post the code first then ask why I'm getting this error.

#### Abstract class - Packet

```
abstract class Packet
{
    // base class!
}
```

#### My first packet

```
public sealed class FirstPacket : Packet
{
    // First packet implementations...
}
```

#### Another Packet

```
public sealed class AnotherPacket : Packet
{
    // Another packet implementations...
}
```

#### Packet OpCodes

```
public enum OpCode
{
    FirstPacket,
    AnotherPacket
}
```

#### Abstract class - BaseConnection

```
public abstract class BaseConnection
{
    private Dictionary<OpCode, Action<Packet>> _packetHandlers;

    public Connection() {
        _packetHandlers = new Dictionary<OpCode, Action<Packet>>();
    }
}
```

#### Finally, my Client

```
public sealed class Client : BaseConnection
{
    public Client() : base() {
        // Here will throw the errors...
        // CS1503   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<Packet>'
        _packetHandlers.Add(OpCode.FirstPacket, OnReceiveFirst);
        _packetHandlers.Add(OpCode.AnotherPacket, OnReceiveAnother);
    }

    public void OnReceiveFirst(FirstPacket packet) {
    }

    public void OnReceiveAnother(AnotherPacket packet) {
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595072/2208678) answer, a derived class is an instance of its base class and no casting involved.

In my code, if both `FirstPacket` and `AnotherPacket` **is** `Packet`, why I have to "cast" using lambda?

```
public sealed class Client : BaseConnection
{
    public Client() : base() {
        // This works...
        _packetHandlers.Add(OpCode.FirstPacket, p => { OnReceiveFirst((FirstPacket)p); });
        _packetHandlers.Add(OpCode.AnotherPacket, p => { OnReceiveAnother((AnotherPacket)p); });
    }

    public void OnReceiveFirst(FirstPacket packet) {
    }

    public void OnReceiveAnother(AnotherPacket packet) {
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because you're going the other way. `p` is a `Packet` and your methods are expecting the derived types. You can transparently pass a `FirstPacket` or a `AnotherPacket` object to a method expecting a `Packet`, but not the other way around. For instance, you could pass a `Giraffe` object to a method expecting an `Animal`, but you can't pass an `Animal` object to a method expecting a `Giraffe` without casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that your lambdas

```
p => { OnReceiveFirst((FirstPacket)p); }
```

would not compile without a cast.

The reason why you can do a cast is that you know enough about the logic of your system to decide that `OnReceiveFirst` would never be called with a parameter of `SecondPacket`. Hence you conclude that the cast is safe.

Compiler, on the other hand, cannot conclude the same thing, so it asks you to supply a cast manually.

Method groups provide a shortcut for situations when no casting is necessary. For example, if you rewrite your `OnReceiveFirst` like this

```
public void OnReceiveFirst(Packet packetOrig) {
    FirstPacket packet = (FirstPacket)packetOrig;
    ...
}
```

you would be able to use it with method group syntax:

```
_packetHandlers.Add(OpCode.FirstPacket, OnReceiveFirst); // Compiles
```

Here, too, casting remains your responsibility, in the sense that if the cast throws an exception, you will be able to trace the error to your own code, not to some compiler magic.

Answer (score 1):

Because `onReceiveFirst` and `OnReceiveAnother` expect a more specific type than `Packet`. `FirstPacket` and `AnotherPacket` are both types of packets, but `AnotherPacket` cannot be substituted for `FirstPacket` and vice versa.

If `OnReceiveFirst` and `OnReceiveAnother` only need to access things declared by the `Packet` type and not anything in the subclass, you could change the definitions to:

```
public void OnReceiveFirst(Packet packet) {}
public void OnReceiveAnother(Packet packet) {}
```